# How can I remaster a text-based Linux distro?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, livecd

I have a Ubuntu minimal install, it is exactly the way I want it when I want to have a fresh install, with the included settings, packages, etc.

It has no desktop, it is completely CLI.

What is an easy way to take the current state that it is in, and make it into a live CD with an installer to an HD? I tried remastersys, but it isn't compatible with Ubuntu CLI, and I'm not fond of the settings remastersys leaves behind.

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative suggestion but not intended to completely poo-poo your idea.

Since ubuntu has headless server distributions (ie, they are CLI only), there is not a huge need to create custom systems stripped down from a GUI desktop distribution.  With regard to settings and such, it is easier to maintain a parallel filesystem tree containing the relevant files that can be archived and unpacked.  What this means is, you create a directory somewhere that mirrors the structure of your root directory.  Eg, if you have upstart service files from `/etc/init` you want to keep, copy them (or use *hard links*) into `/archive/etc/init`.

When you want to deploy a new system somewhere, make a tarball of the archive, install ubuntu server, and then unpack the archive in the root directory.  If the archive has been created such that it is not the `/archive` directory zipped up (which would then unpack into `/archive` and require you to do a lot of manual copying) but instead just the subdirectories thereof, all that stuff will install into the appropriate place (eg, the stuff from `/etc/init` will be in `/etc/init`).  To clarify, in case you are unaware: tarchives are not syncs, meaning if you unpack a tree somewhere where all the directories already exist, those directories are not erased or replaced, but only the duplicate files within them (so your custom `/etc/init` files will go into /etc/init alongside the stuff from the fresh install).

You can duplicate systems very quickly this way with the advantage of using normal installers, and not having to maintain a complete image (and/or one that requires a massive `apt-cache update` post-install, etc).